# Не могу запустить Django через uwsgi

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, wsgi

Пытаюсь залить Django на vps. Не заводится и не могу понять в каком направлении думать.

Через стандартный runserver все работает:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Сайт открывается, все нормально. Но если то же самое сделать через uwsgi, то ничего не получается:

```
$ uwsgi --http :8000 --module my_module.wsgi
```

Имя модуля правильно, команду я пишу находясь в той самой папке с проектом. Но при попытке открыть сайт на 8000 порту возникает Internal server error. При этом в терминал выводится вот такое сообщение:

> no python application found

На всякий случай напишу еще, что на vps уже работает один проект, uwsgi работает в режиме императора, могут ли они конфликтовать?

Comment: Если просто в питоновой консоли набрать `import my_module.wsgi`, импортируется?

Comment: Попробовал, ошибку не выдает. Значит, видимо, импортируется. Плюс попробовал затестить на файлике (uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py). С файликом тоже все ок, открывается на 8000 порту.

Comment: Не уверен что поможет, но попробуйте прописать переменную окружения `export PYTHONPATH=.` перед запуском uwsgi

Comment: А что это такое и что это должно дать?

Comment: Указывает каталоги, из которых можно импортировать модули, в данном случае `.` то есть текущий каталог. Иногда он сам прописывается неявно, иногда его нужно прописывать явно — я не помню, какое конкретно поведение у uwsgi, но вдруг поможет

Comment: Я что-то упустил существенную деталь. При запуске wsgi выдает вот такую ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_module/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named 'django'. 

Ничего не понимаю, потому что я запускаю это дело и под виртуального окружения, и джанго там стоит.

Comment: uwsgi небось установлен за пределами виртуального окружения? https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python.html#virtualenv-support

Comment: Ну на самом деле да, проперся по-детски. Но тем не менее установка uwsgi в виртуальное окружение ничего не решила. Может быть все-таки дело в том, что uwsgi уже работает на этом vps с другим проектом? :(

Comment: No module named 'django' не имеет никакого отношения к другому uwsgi, и вообще их можно запускать сколь угодно много

Comment: Вообще я понял, что моя проблема видимо в том, что я напутал с правами пользователей. Сейчас все работает, если в качестве сокета указать порт при записи uwsgi, но не работает, если сделать это через обычный сокет. В логах написано, что мой пользователь не может получить доступ к этому сокету. Я не очень-то разбираюсь в линуксе, но видимо настройкой прав можно решить эту проблему.